# Make a Java application run itself from the command prompt?

Tags: java, cmd

I have an executable Jar file and to keep it simple, I want to make it so that you can simply double click it on the desktop and it will run. I've tried this:

```
if(args.length == 0){
        String path = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar \"" + decodedPath + "\" -arg");
        System.out.println("java -jar \"" + decodedPath + "\" -arg");
    }
```

To no avail. I assumed that if I told the program to check for the "-arg" argument and it wasn't there, then it would asssume the program was run from the executable, not being called from the command line. So is there a way to make the program open a command prompt and then run itself within it, killing the previous program?

Comment: Do you have a main class property in Manifest file in your jar ?

Comment: With just this technique it will be impossible to achieve the termination of the first program instance.

Comment: AIUI java.exe is needed to interpret the code so you can't make it run itself with java.exe - The best solution is to associate .jar files with java.exe - but I could be in left field here.

Comment: The JRE Installer will usually associate the `.jar` extension with `java.exe` so that doubleclicking an executable jar file simply starts it. See fge's answer on how to make a jar an "executable jar". You can even configure Windows to be able to run `foo.jar` without typing `java -jar` front of it.

Answer (score 1):

As to "run on double click", this is OS dependent.

You can "run a jar" at the command line using:

```
java -jar the.jar
```

This requires that the jar has a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and that this manifest file has a `Main-Class` entry, the argument being the class where your `main()` method is. For instance:

```
Main-Class: org.foobar.mypackage.Foo
```

Comment: I agree that's the way to go. The JRE Installer will usually associate the `.jar` extension with `java -jar ...` so that doubleclicking an executable jar file simply starts it.

Comment: I think you mis- understood me, I want the program to detect whether its being ran from the console or not, if it isn't then it will terminate and then run cmd.exe and then call java -jar e.t.c..

Comment: Well, OK, but your question did not mention that at all. And I don't believe you can actually detect that.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for a similar problem is that I have made a separate GUI program in a JAR file with some `JTextField`s for input and a `JButton` for confirmation. When the button gets clicked, it calls the main method in my other class with those values in a `String` array to start that program and close the GUI form with `frame.setVisible(false)`. I suggest doing something like that, but it's dependent on what type of program you're developing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just pass the necessary command-line flags directly into the JRE *at runtime*! I just figured this out a couple weeks ago, but you can access the `java.library.path` and change it to match necessary library paths through reflection by just putting this code in the front of your main method.

```
try{
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);
    Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
    fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
    fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
}catch(Exception ex){
    // just exit and tell user that there was an error or something similar
}
```

Anyway, I hope that this was helpful. You can also do many similar things by similar code.